Cannot exec a container that has stopped: unknown
Executing docker exec -u user app-php php -v command in a Gitlab CI runner raises the following error:
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: cannot exec a container that has stopped: unknown
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 126

To be noted that everything works fine on local machines when it is executed from Ubuntu, Fedora or macOS.
Job output preceding the error (notice docker ps at the end):
Running with gitlab-runner 17.3.1 (66269445)
  on run01-docker ahzDDsscB, system ID: s_1241bf653f96
Preparing the "docker" executor 00:01
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
Using locally found image version due to "if-not-present" pull policy
Using docker image sha256:*** for docker:latest with digest docker@sha256:*** ...
Preparing environment 00:01
Running on runner-ahzddsscb-project-69-concurrent-0 via run01...
Getting source from Git repository 00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in ***
Checking out 67e5047a as detached HEAD (ref is develop)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:02
Using docker image sha256:*** for docker:latest with digest docker@sha256:*** ...
$ cd app
$ docker-compose pull --quiet --ignore-pull-failures
$ docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans --no-recreate
 Container app-php  Created
 Container app-php  Starting
 Container app-php  Started
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                 COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                  PORTS                                     NAMES
ddbd9feef6d9   0af54085b408                                          "dockerd-entrypoint.…"   2 seconds ago    Up Less than a second   2375-2376/tcp                             runner-ahzddsscb-project-69-concurrent-0-04cc20a5becb9be5-build
56b35d69a5db   docker.***.**/docker/docker-registry/php:8.1   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 minutes ago   Up Less than a second   443/tcp, 9001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8990->80/tcp   app-php

Versions

Gitlab v17.3.3-ee
Docker v27.3.1
Docker Compose v2.29.7

Gitlab CI
image:
    name: docker:latest
stages:
    - build
build app:
    script:
        - cd app
        - docker-compose pull --quiet --ignore-pull-failures
        - docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans --no-recreate
        - docker ps
        - docker exec -u user app-php php -v
    stage: build
    tags:
        - docker

Docker compose
version: "3.7"
services:
    php:
        image: 'docker.domain.fr/docker/docker-registry/php:8.1'
        container_name: 'app-php'
        environment:
            DOCKER_USER_UID: 1000
            DOCKER_USER_GID: 1000
        ports:
            - '8990:80'
        working_dir: '/application'
        volumes:
            - '.:/application:delegated'
            - './nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf'

Runner
...
[[runners]]
    name = "run01-docker"
    executor = "docker"
    ...
    [runners.docker]
        ...
        image = "docker:latest"
        privileged = true
        ...
        volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock",...]

Stuck on this. Any idea welcome.

You seem to have included an image file instead of the error message; can you [edit] the question to replace the image with plain text?  I tend to think of docker exec as more of a debugging command, and you shouldn't need it in normal use, what is your goal using it here?  (Does docker compose run work any better?)

Might be incompatiblity between docker client version and docker daemon version. exec a container that has stopped: unknown What are the logs in docker daemon? What is the docker daemon version? Can you execute docker exec on the host running docker daemon? Etc.
